# Swift Telnet Stream with Authentication

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, tcp, telnet

The following code works great when connecting with TCP to many devices. But trying to connect to a device that asks for a username and password, it does not.

When connecting with putty via telnet, devices like the Cisco SX 80 return a login: prompt after connecting.

But when using the following code, the OpenCompleted event occurs, then HasBytesAvaialable occurs, but the buffer is empty.

Setting the socketSecurityLevel to anything else throws an error because it is plain telnet, not SSL.

Any ideas on what I am missing?

```
func openTcpStream(){
if !tcpHost.isEmpty{
  Stream.getStreamsToHost(withName: tcpHost, port: tcpPort, inputStream: &inputStream, outputStream: &outputStream)
  if inputStream != nil{
    let input: InputStream = inputStream!
    input.delegate = self
    input.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    self.inputStream!.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.none, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socketSecurityLevelKey)
    input.open()

  }
  if outputStream != nil{
    let output: OutputStream = outputStream!
    output.delegate = self
    output.schedule(in: RunLoop.current, forMode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode)
    self.outputStream!.setProperty(StreamSocketSecurityLevel.none, forKey: Stream.PropertyKey.socketSecurityLevelKey)
    output.open()

  }
}
```

}

```
func stream(_ aStream: Stream, handle eventCode: Stream.Event) {
var event = ""
switch  eventCode {
case Stream.Event.openCompleted:
  if writeQueue != ""{
    writeTcpStream(bufferToWrite: writeQueue)

  }
case Stream.Event.hasBytesAvailable:
  if inputStream != nil{
    readTcpStream(inputStream: inputStream)

  }
default:()

}
```

}

```
func readTcpStream(inputStream: InputStream?){
if inputStream != nil{
  let input = inputStream!
  var readBuffer: NSString = ""
  var readByte = [UInt8](repeating:0, count: 512)
  while input.hasBytesAvailable{
    input.read(&readByte, maxLength: readByte.count)
    let tempString = NSString(bytes: readByte, length: readByte.count, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
    if tempString?.length != nil{
      readBuffer = (readBuffer as String) + (tempString! as String) as NSString
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The telnet protocol is not just plain text over a socket. You can find the details in [RFC854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854)

UPDATE: There is an updated spec [RFC5198](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198) you may not need to implement it if you do not need Unicode.